# ¿Porque cuando ejecuto Tkinter python en code visual studio no me ejecuta el title?

Tags: tkinter

> Aquí dejo un ejemplo de código simple que se usa para abrir una ventana, nota(estoy usando chromebook)

```
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Saludo")
ventana.geometry(x= 200,y= 200)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No parece haber un problema con `title`, pero si con [geometry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tk-option-data-types), debería ser `ventana.geometry("200x200")`. Con esa corrección ya funciona.

Comment: Yo pensé que eso era una sintaxis de tkinter que desconocía y que cuando abrías la ventana no se muestra el titulo. Si hubieras agregado a la pregunta el error o, al menos, detalles sobre éste, probablemente hubiera sabido responderte.